# How to create the bean of FindByIndexNameSessionRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I am trying to create the Bean of FindByIndexNameSessionRepository. I need to get all user sessions using it but I am getting the bean error even I already defined it. I am using the Spring Boot Starter 1.5.7

> **Error:** Field sessionRepository required a bean of type 'org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository' that could not be found.
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository' in your
>   configuration.

I am trying to create bean and using it in my configuration, something like that:

```
import com.x.security.SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry;
@Bean
SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<ExpiringSession>(
            this.sessionRepository);
}
@Autowired
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository;
```

My configuration is below

```
http<...>
   .maximumSessions(2)
   .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
    .<other settings>
```

My SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry class is as follow:

```
public class SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<S extends ExpiringSession>
    implements SessionRegistry {
  private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S> sessionRepository;


public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(
        FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S> sessionRepository) {
    Assert.notNull(sessionRepository, "sessionRepository cannot be null");
    this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
     }
     @Override
public List<Object> getAllPrincipals() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry does "
            + "not support retrieving all principals, since Spring Session provides "
            + "no way to obtain that information");
}
@Override
public List<SessionInformation> getAllSessions(Object principal,
        boolean includeExpiredSessions) {
    Collection<S> sessions = this.sessionRepository.findByIndexNameAndIndexValue(
            FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME,
            name(principal)).values();
    List<SessionInformation> infos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (S session : sessions) {
        if (includeExpiredSessions || !Boolean.TRUE.equals(session
                .getAttribute(SpringSessionBackedSessionInformation.EXPIRED_ATTR))) {
            infos.add(new SpringSessionBackedSessionInformation<S>(session,
                    this.sessionRepository));
        }
    }
    return infos;
}

@Override
public SessionInformation getSessionInformation(String sessionId) {
    S session = this.sessionRepository.getSession(sessionId);
    if (session != null) {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionInformation<S>(session,
                this.sessionRepository);
    }
    return null;
}

/*
 * This is a no-op, as we don't administer sessions ourselves.
 */
 @Override
public void refreshLastRequest(String sessionId) {
}

/*
 * This is a no-op, as we don't administer sessions ourselves.
 */
 @Override
public void registerNewSession(String sessionId, Object principal) {
}

/*
 * This is a no-op, as we don't administer sessions ourselves.
 */
 @Override
public void removeSessionInformation(String sessionId) {
}

/**
 * Derives a String name for the given principal.
 *
 * @param principal as provided by Spring Security
 * @return name of the principal, or its {@code toString()} representation if no name
 * could be derived
 */

protected String name(Object principal) {
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        return ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    }
    if (principal instanceof Principal) {
        return ((Principal) principal).getName();
    }
    return principal.toString();
}

}
```

My pom snippet is as follows

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you've got Spring Session configured properly (with Spring Boot `1.5.x` that would be by setting `spring.session.store-type` configuration property to `redis`, or explicitly by using `@EnableRedisHttpSession`), you should be able to use `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends ExpiringSession>`. For example:

```
@Autowired
FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends ExpiringSession> sessionRepository;
```

Comment: Thanks Vedran, I was missing @EnableRedisHttpSession