# Lateinit property not intialized "FindByIndexNameSessionRepository"

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, spring-session

I am particularly new to Spring Boot and Hibernate, I have some trouble with `lateinit` in the code below.

To give you a simple overview, I am implementing a simple Hibernate interceptor for `onSave`. So every time the `Admin` modifies a certain `User` in db and saves it. The `onSave` event will be triggered. Then basically validates if the `entity` is of type `user` then log the entity, and find the `entity.username` in the `SessionRepository` if found log the `id`.

Everytime I process `this.sessions.findByPrincipalName(user).values` in `searchByPrincipalName` I have an exception that `sessions` has not been initialized.

My understanding of `lateinit` is that, at object usage it will be initialized.

Maybe I am missing something? or I misunderstood the concept?

**Code:**

```
@Component
class UserChangeInterceptor: EmptyInterceptor() {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var sessions: FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<out Session>

    val logger = loggerFor<UserChangeInterceptor>()

    override fun onSave(
        entity: Any?,
        id: Serializable?,
        state: Array<out Any>?,
        propertyNames: Array<out String>?,
        types: Array<out Type>?
    ): Boolean {
        if (entity is User) {
            logger.info("UserChangeInterceptor::onSave $entity")
            searchByPrincipalName(entity.username).forEach {
                logger.info("UserChangeInterceptor::onSave -> ${it.id}")
            }
        }
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types)
    }

    private fun searchByPrincipalName(user: String): MutableCollection<out Session> {
        return this.sessions.findByPrincipalName(user).values
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create the bean of FindByIndexNameSessionRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347043/how-to-create-the-bean-of-findbyindexnamesessionrepository)

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana this does not fix my problem. I already am injecting it.