# FindByIndexNameSessionRepository cannot be null in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am trying to implement remember function for my Spring Security Application. And I used Redis also. I configured, `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry` beans. But when I try to `@Autowired` `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` I got the following error,

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sessionRepository
> cannot be null

The code is as follows,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessionRepository;
    
    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(this.sessionRepository);
    }
}
```

`Handler.java`

```
@Component
public class Handler {

    private @Autowired SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
    private @Autowired FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessionRepository;
    
}
```

And Redis Session Configuration,

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class SessionConfig {

    private final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    public SessionConfig(ObjectProvider<RedisConnectionFactory> redisConnectionFactory) {
        this.redisConnectionFactory = redisConnectionFactory.getIfAvailable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisOperations<String, Object> sessionRedisOperations() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(this.redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisSessionRepository redisSessionRepository(RedisOperations<String, Object> sessionRedisOperations) {
        return new RedisSessionRepository(sessionRedisOperations);
    }
}
```

I get errors like,

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sessionRepository
> cannot be null Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.session.security.SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry]:
> Circular reference involving containing bean 'securityConfig' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionRegistry' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> sessionRepository cannot be null Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionRegistry' defined in class path
> resource [SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.session.security.SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry]:
> Circular reference involving containing bean 'securityConfig' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionRegistry' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> sessionRepository cannot be null

Also it says,

> No beans of 'FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session>' type
> found.

So what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347043/how-to-create-the-bean-of-findbyindexnamesessionrepository?

Comment: @jccampanero I checked it and I put `@EnableRedisHttpSession` but didn't work. Keep saying `sessionRepository cannot be null`

Comment: I see... The stack trace indicates that there is some kind of circular dependency in your configuration. Please, can you remove the ```@EnableWebSecurity``` from your class? Just let the ```@Configuration``` annotation. It is possible that other configurations are interfering with your class.

Comment: @jccampanero I removed `@EnableWebSecurity` but still I get the same error. I have updated the question and put `Handler.java` and Redis `SessionConfig.java` classes. Could you please check them also? And also it says No bean found for `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` type.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the question. I posted an answer with a possible solution. Please, can you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, I am not sure, because this circular dependency error...

In any case, the problem probably is happening because you do not actually have a `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` injected in your Spring context, at least not the one you are trying to configure, but a `SessionRepository`, because you are defining a bean of type [`RedisSessionRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisSessionRepository.html) and this interface implements `SessionRepository`, not `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`. Please, try to use a [`RedisIndexedSessionRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisIndexedSessionRepository.html) instead, something like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class SessionConfig {

    private final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    public SessionConfig(ObjectProvider<RedisConnectionFactory> redisConnectionFactory) {
        this.redisConnectionFactory = redisConnectionFactory.getIfAvailable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisOperations<String, Object> sessionRedisOperations() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(this.redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public FindByIndexNameSessionRepository redisSessionRepository(RedisOperations<String, Object> sessionRedisOperations) {
        return new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(sessionRedisOperations);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for putting your time and effort to solve this issue, sir. I really appreciate that. I did this but now I am getting an error saying the are two beans redisSessionRepository and sessionRepository. I even commented the redisSessionRepository but it didn't work out? Is there any other way to create a bean for `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`, sir?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer. You need to define just one bean, not both. can you try, please? What error are you getting?

Comment: I will leave now, but please, post any comment you consider appropriate, I will try to review it asap

Comment: @HAthukorala Had you got any advance in the resolution of the problem?

Comment: Hi Sir, I am sorry for my delay. I couldn't check this past few days. I just checked it and unfortunately the error is still there, sir. It keep saying `sessionRepository` is null.

Comment: And also instead of `RedisOperations<String, Object>` I had to use `RedisOperations<Object, Object>`, sir

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please don't call me sir, jccampanero or jc it's fine ;). Please can you create a repository on GitHub and share your code? It will give me the ability to review your it and be able to provide you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Today I tried again and I put `@Lazy` to `sessionRegistry` in `Handler.java` so now it's working fine without any issues. Thank you very much for the answer and putting your all effort and time to solve this issue. I really appreciate that.

Comment: You're welcome @HAthukorala, thank you. I am very happy to hear that you were finally able to solve your problem.